# how to acces arguments using while loop in java

Tags: java, spring

how do I access the contents of arguments starting from the first index using "while loop"?
I tried this one:

[image]

and get this error:

[image]

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test `i < args.length` *before* using `args[i]`.  You're testing `i` at the top of your loop (wrong test, BTW, you want <, not <=), but by that point, it's too late: your `while` already accessed `args[i]` and died.

Try this instead:

```
while (i < args.length && !args[i].equals("Dua puluh")) {
    textUlang = textUlang + "ulang";
    ++i;
}
```

That way, you're always sure that `i` is a valid index before you actually try to do `args[i]`.

Comment: Thanks, i'm really grateful for your help